# nginx SSL handshake fails on requests from mobile devices with "SSL_BYTES_TO_CIPHER_LIST:inappropriate fallback"

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I am trying to find a solution for this error (full error message is `[crit] 556#0: *1940 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140A1175:SSL routines:SSL_BYTES_TO_CIPHER_LIST:inappropriate fallback) while SSL handshaking, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: 0.0.0.0:443`)

I have read multiple similar questions (like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/663290/in-nginx-error-log-ssl-bytes-to-cipher-listinappropriate-fallback) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28010492/nginx-critical-error-with-ssl-handshaking), but they all treat the problem with browsers, and my clients are mobile apps.

Also, they all talk about having/not having `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV`  enabled in openssl. After finding [this tutorial](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html#Poodle_and_TLS-FALLBACK-SCSV) about strong SSL security on nginx, I am even more baffled. In the tutorial it says that

> OpenSSL 1.0.1 has TLSFALLBACKSCSV in 1.0.1j and higher.

On my system (Ubuntu trusty) I get

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

I have tried upgrading to a newer version, but this seems to be the latest version for Ubuntu trusty. It is worth mentioning that this errors started occurring quite recently, and without apparent reason. The errors don't show up always (the behaviour is quite random actually).

However, this is worrying, since their frequency is getting higher and higher and important data is being lost because of these unsuccessful requests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what does ssllabs.com says about your server?

Comment: It gets a C overall rating. An important line is "This server is vulnerable to the POODLE attack. If possible, disable SSL 3 to mitigate. Grade capped to C." But this is weird because in nginx docs (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols) the allowed default ssl protocols are TLS versions only... I will specify it in the nginx.conf to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: So added the `ssl_protocols` inside my  server configuration and now I am getting another error : `SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094085:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ccs received early) while SSL handshaking`

Comment: You should read https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS and take inspiration from https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ for your HTTPS/TLS configuration of nginx

Comment: Will do and post my findings in a response. Thanks you very much, Tom, those are amazing resources that I did not know about. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, thanks to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2195875/tom), things started working out :)
The steps he indicated were the following, and I suggest this approach for everyone, not just those who have errors.

1. Go to [the Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) and generate a configuration for your server.
2. Modify the file accordingly for your needs.
3. Go to [SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and do a server test for your newly created server.
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until your grade is A.
5. ???
6. Profit!

The important part is to read and understand as much as possible every single configuration setting you are putting in your files.
Good luck!

Comment: This worked well for me. I upgraded openssl beforehand. Also regenerated my letsencrypt certs as well (unsure if this was required, but may have helped)